# how to add an artboard to a document in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I wrote a script in JavaScript for Adobe Illustrator CC 2017. In this script I am trying to add artboard to the document in function, but it isn't working.

Here code:

```js
function addArtboard() {
    var doc = app.documents.add(null,1000,1000);
    doc = app.activeDocument;
    var artboards = doc.artboards;
     artboards.add([0 , 0, 1000, 1000]);
}
 
addArtboard();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problems seems to be the measurement of your new artboard.
Take a look into the scripting guide [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/illustrator/scripting.html).

The add method takes an `artboardRect` as argument.
[image: screenshot from scripting guide]

The code below creates a new doc and adds an artboard next to the first one.

```
/* global app, $ */
function addArtboard() {
  var doc = app.documents.add(); // create a doc with defaults
  var firstArtBoard = doc.artboards[0]; // get the default atboard
    // inspect its properties
  for(var prop in firstArtBoard) {
    // exclude protptypes
    if(firstArtBoard.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      $.writeln(prop);
    }
  }
  // there is a rect property
  // take a look at the values
  $.writeln(firstArtBoard.artboardRect);
  // create a artboard with the same size and an
  // offset of 5 points to the right
  var x1 = firstArtBoard.artboardRect[2] + 10;
  var y1 = firstArtBoard.artboardRect[1];
  var x2 = x1 + firstArtBoard.artboardRect[2];
  var y2 = firstArtBoard.artboardRect[3];
  doc.artboards.add([x1, y1, x2, y2]);
}

addArtboard();
```